# Selenium Unable to locate element: Bug

Tags: python, selenium

i try to do something in selenium, i need to send username and pass but ı got this error. I work on pythonanywhere

i tried time.sleep(20-60), implicty wait.

```py
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
    display.start()
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    time.sleep(30)
    username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input")
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input")
```

My Error is :

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input"}
```

Comment: Without sharing html code we cannot really help you

Comment: ı dont have html code i scrape twitter tweets

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is loaded successfully and user name field is displayed using WebDriverWait.

**Need the below Imports**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Script:**

```
userName = WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input")))
# now try entering the value in userName
userName.send_keys("valueGoesHere")
```

Comment: Hello it cant work, gets me this error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: @supputuri

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, though it's in Scala, the selector should still be correct though.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[name='session[username_or_email]']")).get(1).sendKeys("some username")
    driver.findElements(By.name("session[password]")).get(1).sendKeys("some password")
```

I initially tried

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='session[username_or_email]']")).sendKeys("some username")`

but that failed, element not interactable, but noticed that it had a size of 3, so tried the findElements method which worked with an index of 1